# Let $ f$ be a function such that $|f(u)-f(v)|\leq|u-v|$ for all real $u$ and $v$ in an interval $[a,b]$

Tags: definite-integrals

Let $ f$ be a function such that $|f(u)-f(v)|\leq|u-v|$ for all real $u$ and $v$ in an interval $[a,b]$.Then:
$(i)$Prove that $f$ is continuous at each point of $[a,b]$.

$(ii)$Assume that $f$ is integrable on $[a,b]$.Prove that,$|\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx-(b-a)f(c)|\leq\frac{(b-a)^2}{2}$,where $a\leq c \leq b$

I tried to solve second part,First part i could not get idea.
$|\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx-(b-a)f(c)|=|\int_{a}^{b}f(x)-f(c)dx|=\int_{a}^{b}|f(x)-f(c)|dx\leq\int_{a}^{b}|x-c|dx\leq\int_{a}^{c}(c-x)dx+\int_{c}^{b}(x-c)dx$

But i am not getting desired result,what have i done wrong in this?Or is there another method to prove it.Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prove the first assertion, let $\varepsilon > 0$ and let $c \in [a,b]$. Since
$$
|f(x) - f(c)| \underset{\text{by assumption}}\leq |x-c| < \varepsilon
$$
if $|x-c| < \varepsilon$,
it follows that $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$.

To prove the second assertion, note that, since $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$, by the mean-value theorem for integrals there is some $c \in [a,b]$ such that
$
\int_{a}^{b}f = f(c)(b-a),
$
*i.e.*
$\int_{a}^{b}f - [f(c)(b-a)] = 0 \leq (b-a)^{2}/2.$

I hope these are helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

$$(b-a)^2 \geqslant (b-c)^2 + (c-a)^2$$

Comment: How this inequality is proved?

Comment: @diya: $b-a = (b-c) +(c-a) \implies (b-a)^2 = (b-c)^2 + (c-a)^2 +2(b-c)(c-a)$ and $(b-c)(c-a) > 0$ if $a < c < b$.

Comment: You are on the right track. Just do the integrals and apply the inequality.

Comment: Thank you very much,i understood.

Comment: You're welcome. Keep in mind this is true for any $c \in [a,b]$ as you are trying to show - not just for some c give by the mean value theorem.